# Why does adding a class affect the reported height within the same loop using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a timelined comments feature for part of my app.  Inspired by facebook's new timelined profiles.

As an example here is a screenshot of the current display.

[image: Example]

As you can see the comment/reply boxes fill up all vertical space.

In order to do this I have used jQuery to do the following to the `<li>` elements in the ordered list of comments with nested replies.

- collect the items into an object
- iterate over each one and get its individual height all the while building a left and right variable with the total height of the left
  hand side boxes and the total of the right hand side boxes
- I then check which out of the left and right have the higher total height and apply either a timeline-left or timeline-right class to
  the next comment box.

This all seems very simple however I ran into a huge problem which I am at a loss to explain.

If I apply the class within the initial loop (iteration over the elements) The height variable gets effected within the loop.  It appears to be adding them together rather than replacing the current one.  This of course causes the boxes to be switched to the incorrect sides and therefore fails to close the gaps.  Although not relevant to the functionality I added the heights as an attribute to each element in order to better see what was going on.  And without a shadow of a doubt.  As soon I add the class 'timeline-left' within the same loop as the height detection, the height variable combines each loop rather than reflecting the individual elements value.

To work around this I have come up with what I consider to be a very ugly method solve the issue.

- I iterate through the objects and build an array of values (height,side) for each box.
- I then iterate AGAIN through this new array and apply the classes to each box.

Now this actually works fine and performance is also fine.  While I usually adhere to the whole pre-optimization is bad mentality.  In this case I just cannot let it lie as surely there should be no reason to iterate through the elements more than once?

Here is the current (ugly) code I am using which collects the data about each element and then re-loops a second time to apply the classes:

```
    var side = "left",
         $timeline = $("#timeline"),
         $elements = $timeline.children("li").not(".timeline-spine"),
         newwidth = parseInt(($("#rightcolumnwrapper").width() / 2) - 26),
         length = $elements.length,
         array = [],
         $i = 0,
         leftheight = 0,
         rightheight = 0,
         side = "left";

     while ($i < length) {

         var $this = $elements.eq($i),
             height = $this.outerHeight(true);

         if (leftheight > rightheight) {
             side = "right";
         } else {
             side = "left";
         }

         array.push({
             "side": side,
             "height": height
         });

         if (side == "right") {
             var rightheight = rightheight + height + 25;
         } else if (side == "left") {
             var leftheight = leftheight + height + 25;
         }
         $i++;
     }

     $.each(array, function (index, value) {

         var $timelineItem = $("#timeline").children("li").not(".timeline-spine").eq(index);

         $timelineItem.attr("data-height", array[index]["height"]).addClass("timeline-" + array[index]["side"]).children(".window-wrapper").width(newwidth).siblings("#pointer").addClass("pointer-" + array[index]["side"]);


//The code below is not relevant to the question but is left in for completeness

         if ($timelineItem.is("#timeline-bottom")) {
             $timelineItem.find("#pointer").css({
                 "left": (newwidth + 21) + "px"
             });
         } else if ($timelineItem.is("#loves-capsule")) {
             if ($timelineItem.find("#love-main").height() > $this.find("#loves-wrapper").height() - 33) {
                 $timelineItem.height("176px").find("#loves-wrapper").css({
                     "height": "174px",
                     "margin-bottom": "-35px"
                 }).end().find("#love-footer").show();
             }
         }

     });
```

Is there anything I can do to get this into one loop without (and I really cannot explain why) effecting the heights reported for each element?

Note:  There is some other stuff going on at the end is not really relevant to the question however I have left it in for code completeness.

EDIT:  Just to be clear there is no css styling other than clear:left; float:left and clear:right; float:right; in either of the css rules that I am adding. Just in case anyone thought I may be styling them to modify the height.

Comment: Can you simplify the question? It seems you have a lot of text and code that's not necessary to answer the question which makes it harder to determine what you want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible "one loop" implimentation:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var $timeline, $elements, $wrapper, columns;

    $timeline = $("#timeline");
    $elements = $timeline.children("li").not(".timeline-spine");    
    $wrapper = $("#rightcolumnwrapper"); 
    columns = {
        left : { 
            height : 0,
            stack : []
        },
        right : {
            height : 0,
            stack : []
        }
    };

    $elements.each(function(index){
        var $obj = $(this), col, side, obj_height;

        obj_height = $obj.outerHeight(true);

        if ( index === 0 ||  columns.left.height < columns.right.height ) {
            // create a local reference to the column 
            col = columns.left;
            side = "left";
        }
        else {
            col = columns.right;
            side = "right";
        }
        // Do stuff with this node 
        $obj.addClass('timeline-'+side); //...

        // Add object height to container height
        col.height = col.height + obj_height;
        // push raw dom node to stack
        col.stack.push(this);
    });


});
```

However manipulating an entire "stack" of nodes may be faster than doing the same operations on every iteration of .each()

```
$.each(columns,function(index){
    // index is left or right 
    var $stack = $( this.stack );
    $stack.addClass('timeline-'+index)//.doMoreThings()...
});
```

Comment: Thats a fantastic approach, far more elegant than my quick and dirty attempt.  However it doesn't seem to work, the elements are not moved correctly as they are in my own.  i'm going to do some console logging with the variables in your code to see if I can find out why.

Comment: Sadly... (especially as I like your approach so much better than my own) if I log the obj_heights returned it displays the same accumulating height behaviour as my own code when used in a single loop.  And again if I comment out the 'addClass' line the heights are reported correctly. I really am at a loss to explain why.  If it was easier to do so I woul get a jsfiddle up for you all to see, but the html/css are quite complex.

Comment: The good news is, when using a second loop as you described (with the stack method) the code works perfectly.  It is shorter and infinitely more elegant the my quick ugly attempt therefore although it hasn't actually answered my question regarding the node manipulation within the loop causing a height miscalculation, i feel it deserves to be marked as the correct answer.  Many thanks. :)

Comment: There was a semicolon error at line 21. I tried running this through the console with li's that where 11

Comment: EDIT: I tried running this through the console and obj_height shows correct height for each LI + column.side.height should show the accumulated total for the LIs in that column. Otherwise the comparison won´t work.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** After further review, I think your problem with height is this part:

```
.attr("data-height", height)
```

Try calling "data-height" something else, or use `.data()` instead of `.attr()`;

I believe this (single loop) is equivalent to what you posted. Updated source, comments in source below.

```
var side = "left",
    $timeline = $("#timeline"),
    $elements = $timeline.children("li").not(".timeline-spine"),
    newwidth = parseInt(($("#rightcolumnwrapper").width() / 2), 10) - 26,
    length = $elements.length,
    array = [],
    $i = 0,
    leftheight = 0,
    rightheight = 0,
    side = "left",
    $this = {},
    height = 0;
while ($i < length) {
    $this = $elements.eq($i);
    height = $this.outerHeight(true);
    side = (leftheight > rightheight) ? "right" : "left";
    // unnecessary with only one loop
    /*
    array.push({
        "side": side,
        "height": height
    });
    */
    // var $timelineItem = $("#timeline").children("li").not(".timeline-spine").eq(index); === var $this = $elements.eq($i)
    $this.attr("data-heightY", height).addClass("timeline-" + side).children(".window-wrapper").width(newwidth).siblings("#pointer").addClass("pointer-" + side);
    if ($this.is("#timeline-bottom")) {
        $this.find("#pointer").css({
            "left": (newwidth + 21) + "px"
        });
    } else if ($this.is("#loves-capsule")) {
        if ($this.find("#love-main").height() > ($this.find("#loves-wrapper").height() - 33)) {
            $this.height("176px").find("#loves-wrapper").css({
                "height": "174px",
                "margin-bottom": "-35px"
            }).end().find("#love-footer").show();
        }
    }
    if (side == "right") {
        rightheight += height + 25;
    } else if (side == "left") {
        leftheight += height + 25;
    }
    $i++;
}
// now unnecessary
/*
$.each(array, function (index, value) {
    var $timelineItem = $("#timeline").children("li").not(".timeline-spine").eq(index);
    $timelineItem.attr("data-height", array[index]["height"]).addClass("timeline-" + array[index]["side"]).children(".window-wrapper").width(newwidth).siblings("#pointer").addClass("pointer-" + array[index]["side"]);
    if ($timelineItem.is("#timeline-bottom")) {
        $timelineItem.find("#pointer").css({
            "left": (newwidth + 21) + "px"
        });
    } else if ($timelineItem.is("#loves-capsule")) {
        if ($timelineItem.find("#love-main").height() > $this.find("#loves-wrapper").height() - 33) {
            $timelineItem.height("176px").find("#loves-wrapper").css({
                "height": "174px",
                "margin-bottom": "-35px"
            }).end().find("#love-footer").show();
        }
    }
});
*/
```

Comment: Thanks pete... The part that you commented out saying that I dont seem to be using at all actually is where rightheight and leftheight are calculated.  They add the height of the current element onto the current total leftheight/rightheight then add a further 25px margin to adjust for the element margin.  I will give your suggestion a try with those modifcations back in and let you know. cheers.

Comment: And unfortunately the same height calculation problem exists (your attempt was very similar to my first).  As soon as I remove the addclass line, it reports the correct height.